# App rejected for using an icon that is an "Apple trademark image"

Tags: ios, iphone

I just got rejected from the App Store for this reason:

> We’ve reviewed your app and determined that we cannot post this version of your iPhone application to the App Store because of an Apple trademark image.
>
> You may not use the Apple Logo or any other Apple-owned graphic symbol, logo, or icon on or in connection with web sites, products, packaging, manuals, promotional/advertising materials, or for any other purpose except pursuant to an express written trademark license from Apple, such as a reseller agreement.

Now, I believe the infringing image is this one - however it is clearly NOT an iPhone and it's used to help you find your friends phones around you.. my artist drew it, it's not an iPhone.

[image]

The "infringing Apple trademark image" is shown above

What can I do about this?? This is ridiculous.

Comment: Get rid of the little circle at the bottom, that should make it look different enough from an iphone for them

Comment: You can not do anything about it i guess, you have an artist, so he could make a new one and better one seems to me.

Comment: It may not be an iPhone to you but as far as Apple see it, it looks like an iPhone. I also think it looks like an iPhone because of the button at the bottom.

Comment: this IS sad but IMO this isnt programming related and doesnt really belong on SO

Comment: You should first engage conversation with apple on the app rejection screen to ask exactly what image is problematic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is in no way related to a practical programming problem in the scope of the site.

Comment: This is not off-topic. It is a reasonable question faced by a software developer to an audience that may certainly be able to help. Stack Overflow is slowly being destroyed by individuals who have nothing better to do than to be pedantic about questions.

Comment: for me I have just removed the screen shot that has the apple logo ,, and reply to the apple in resolution center ,, 1 hour later they approved , without new release build

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [**iPod, iPhone, and iPad Icons**](https://developer.apple.com/softwarelicensing/agreements/icons.php) section of the **Licensing and Trademarks Developer** website.
I'm attaching the Apple's iPhone icon that caused rejection.

[image]

There is nothing you can do about it. You have to redesign the icon so it does not look similar to Apple's one.

**UPDATE**

I found another example of iPhone image on [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/ios7/) that could have been the reason for rejection.

[image]

Comment: We redesigned it to look like an Android phone instead, let's see what happens..

Comment: @user3597601 what happened?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an image that has the likeness of an iPhone in it, I can almost guarantee you that's the reason it got rejected. I recall reading a book where a guy developed an app with an iPhone image in it, and got rejected. My suggestion is to use something else, so long as it's not Apple related, and I bet you'll be fine.

Please refer:https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html

Comment: for me I have just removed the screen shot that has the apple logo ,, and reply to the apple in resolution center ,,